# How can I use an LSTM to predict new variables from the same time series?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Let X_1 be a 1D vector of t...N time-steps describing the speed of a car and X_2 and X_3 vectors describing the distance and velocity of the car at each time step. Both X_2 and X_3 have the same dimension as X_1. Assuming that I wish to predict X_3 for time steps t'...N' given X_1 and X_2 for time steps t'...N' (i.e. corresponding time steps), what is/are the most appropriate LSTM configuration/s to use in this case?

It is often the case to use LSTM to predict new time steps given information in the past -- e.g. in this case predict X_3 @ time step t+1 from X_1 and X_2 @ time step t. Here however the aim is different; it is not to predict into the 'future' but rather to predict a new variable for time steps corresponding to those time steps found in the input (e.g. X_1 and X_2) time series.

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detail? You have X<1> and X<2> as an input and your expectation that output will be Y<1> and Y<2>. It means your RNN will be many-to-many. You are saying "I am not looking to predict the future". What does it mean ?

Comment: @drorhun. It was a bit confusing. I rephrased it. Please see above

Comment: You can find your question's answer from here https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/machine-translation-encoder-decoder-model-7e4867377161